# How do I use an enum from another class when I have an enum with the same value I am using in the current class? C++

Tags: c++, enums

I am having trouble returning a function that requires me returning the enum "BEGIN" from the first class. The problem I am running into is that I am using a separate enum list in the current class I am working from. So when I go to return the function it is taking it from the current class and not the derived class. Anyone know how to fix this?
header class:

```
enum Token {
    PRINT, BEGIN, END, IF, THEN}
LexItem(Token token, string lexeme, int line) {
        this->token = token;
        this->lexeme = lexeme;
        this->lnum = line;
    }
```

function class:

```
LexItem getNextToken(istream& in, int& linenum){
enum TokState { BEGIN, INID, INSTRING, ININT, INREAL, INCOMMENT, SIGN }
if(lexeme.compare("begin")){
   LexItem item = LexItem(BEGIN, lexeme, linenum); //error on LexItem no instance of constructor
   return item;}
```

I think it is because it is using the TokState begin instead of the one from Token. Not sure how to fix. I am not able to change the enums in either class.

Comment: Use `enum class` instead.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new at programming, what do you mean? What does that syntax look like?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum scroll down to **Scoped enumerations**

Comment: Used Token::BEGIN and it took the error message off. Thanks!